# Conversion of NSString to NSNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to convert a string value to a NSNumber with the code below, which is stored in a CoreData database:

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

NSLog(@"OrigLoc: '%@', OrigLat '%@'", [item objectForKey: @"origLocHorizontal"], [item objectForKey: @"originLatitude"]);

[tour setOriginLatitude: [f numberFromString:[item objectForKey: @"originLatitude"]]];
[tour setOriginLongitude: [f numberFromString:[item objectForKey: @"originLongitude"]]];
[tour setOrigLocHorizontal: [f numberFromString:[item objectForKey: @"origLocHorizontal"]]];
[tour setOrigLocVertical: [f numberFromString:[item objectForKey: @"origLocVertical"]]];
```

The result of the NSLog is : "OrigLoc: '206.195', OrigLat '41.824989318847656'"

A dump on the iPhone 6 of 'tour' gives: 'origLocHorizontal = "206.195";'
A dump on the iPhone 5 gives: origLocHorizontal = 206195;

(note the difference of "xxx")

This works fine for a 'double' field in CoreData, but not for a 'float'. A value of 25.5 is stored as 25500 instead. This seems to happen on non 64 bit iOS devices, although that might just be coincidental to the real problem.

Anybody any suggestions what this problem might cause?

Comment: Maybe a locale problem? `.` is commonly used as the thousand separator (as opposed to the decimal separator, which is a comma) in most non-anglophone countries.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant But those locales use the same convention for `double` and `float`.

Comment: We thought it was comma and full-stop first, as that is another difference between the devices. But it does not explain why it works for one value, and not for another.

Comment: If this data is a number then why is it in an `NSString` in the first place?

Comment: It comes from an XML file, I added a description.

Comment: Why are you using `NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle`? If this is coming in from a file it should have a set format, preferably without any separators...

Comment: I added some more info

Comment: If this is only on 32 bit devices maybe that can be the problem. On 64 bit architecture doubles and floats are both 8 bytes(?) and on 32 bit its 8 and 4 bytes. Altho CoreData should handle that(?)... I know that can cause problems if user migrates between devices. Something stored as 4 bytes tun read back as 8 bytes..

Comment: @PeterSegerblom That's not true as I understand it; `sizeof(float)` and `sizeof(double)` is the same under 32- and 64-bit systems.

Comment: Have you tried [NSNumber numberWithString: ...], [number stringValue], to see what happens?  If you're using an internal xml format to your internal objects, you want less fancy parsing that localization can break.  You want to bring localization in only to values that the user is going to see (basically very last step).  NSNumberFormatter I believe will do different things based on the user's settings, could break your app without even knowing what went wrong.

Comment: @KirkSpaziani Where do you see: ` [NSNumber numberWithString: ...]`?

Comment: Blah - you're right, no [NSNumber numberWithString:], but there is [myString doubleValue], etc.  Point is avoiding NSNumberFormatter unless it's for user visible formatting

Comment: @trojanfoe your right. I was wrong on that one. Altho when i looked it up i found that its the same size for float and double but for some reason CGFloat differ 4bytes on 32 and 8bytes on 64.

Comment: Yes, `@([myString doubleValue])` is a good way to go. But I doubt that is is a numeric conversion problem, The OP need to prove or dis-prove that as per my answer.

Comment: What about this. In a locale where the '.' is the thousand separator, and if there are 3 digits on the right, the system automatically sees it as a thousand marker. Double values have more digits to the right, so the system realises that it is the decimal marker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not NSNumberFormatter, it is elsewhere in the code.

Break up the statement that isn't working into several statements and find the problem. First get the NSString, then convert to an NSNumber, then set in tour. Log after each statement.

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];

NSString *numberAsString = [item objectForKey: @"originLatitude"];
NSLog(@"numberAsString: %@", numberAsString);

NSNumber *number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:numberAsString];
```

or

```
NSNumber *number = @[numberAsString:doubleValue]);

NSLog(@"number: %@", number);

[tour setOriginLatitude: number];
// NSLog from Core Data
```

Note: you really don't need to set setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle, probably shouldn't.

Comment: NSLog(@"OrigLoc string: '%@', OrigLoc '%f'", [item objectForKey: @"origLocHorizontal"], [[tour origLocHorizontal] floatValue]); gives "OrigLoc string: '208.461', OrigLoc '208461.000000'"

Comment: Removing NSNumberFormatDecimalStyle and adding     [f setDecimalSeparator:@"."]; seems to work. Verifying that now.